# Windows 10 November update (10586) resets associations

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association, windows-10-v1511

Windows 10 November update resets associations to MS defaults, for instance .m3u is re-associated to Groove (which is unable to play that since it contains internet streams). How to automatically revert all associations to the state before the update?

Comment: the november update is technically a new OS and not a small update

Comment: @magicandre1981 Could you provide some rationale for `is technically a new OS`? I am considering that as a same OS: Windows 10.

Comment: no, the original Windows10 was build 10240 and all updates updated the revision 10240.xxxxx. The November update is a new build 10586 which is a new OS and the update process it an OS Upgrade like going from 8.1 to 10. Here MS changes often a lot of settings back.

Comment: @magicandre1981 How to prevent MS from doing that? :) I do not want each few months to setup it again:(

Comment: submit it in the feedback app and hope/pray that MS listens to feedback

Comment: @TN. - You can't prevent it.  The EULA is specific with this regard.  You are basically required to run the current build of Windows 10.  Windows 10 Professional allows you to defer that for a few months.  Windows 10 Enterprise offers several options including a long term support branch.  In all cases you are required to install updates and use the most recent build of said support branch.

Comment: I am just wondering that I am the only one who has problem with the reset... Or, how are you solving this issue: not using Windows 10 at all, or manually re-associating the file extensions, or using some script to restore the associations?